# How can I easily move multiple artboards in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

All artboards in my current project are organized according to page and iteration. As I'm adding more and more, I've come to the edge of the workable area in Illustrator.

I'd rather not break my organization system or have to move each artboard one-by-one to shift everything to where there's room.

Is there a way to just grab all boards and move them?

Also, I've tried the "Rearrange Artboards..." dialog, but it messed up my ordering.

Answer (score 13):

In more recent versions of Illustrator, one can simply **Shift-Click** to select more than a single artboard and move them.

---

Original answer posted in 2014

## CS6 or older....

Unfortunately, Adobe hasn't seen a scenario where a user would want to move more than one artboard at a time. I'm not certain why this limitation exists. However, there's **no way** to manually move two or more artboards at the same time.

The ***only*** way to move more than one artboard simultaneously is via `Object > Artboards > Rearrange...` which may or may not suit your needs. It allows you to organize the layout of artboards automatically. There are some limitations, such as no overlapping artboards and a strict adherence to a grid system, but I still find it useful at times.

In order for it to operate somewhat as expected, you need to "stack" or "order" the artboard list. For example, it will always assume the artboard created 4th is the 4th artboard if it appears as the 4th item in the Artboard Panel. You can adjust the (for lack of a better term) "stacking" order of the artboards by click-dragging artboards in the **Artboard Panel** into the order you want them. Then run the Rearrange command.

Answer (score 4):

I have a tip maybe it could help.

1. make some dummy boxes (or group your objects you want it in the same artboard).
2. each one of those dummy boxes represent a new Artboards, arrange it the way you want with your favorit tools (smart guides, align panel, dynamic transformation ..etc).
3. after you finished the alignment and arrangement of those boxes, click on the artboard icon to switch your workspace to be in the artboard editing mode.
4. you will notice that your cursor switched to move symbol. and every time you step your cursor over one of your box, illustrator will create a new artboard with the same dimension and location of the box you stepped over.
5. delete the very first artboard and now you have all your artboards aligned and arranged the way you want easily.

please notice, if one of the boxes is located out of your first artboard, you can convert it to artboard by clicking over the artboard option button in the artboard panel and click convert to artboard.

that's it.

the following screen captures as an example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't completely follow what you're proposing, but it sounds like you're making use of Illustrator's ability to create artboards by clicking on content. So, especially if I have shapes the size of the artboards, I could potentially just move the content of the artboards, then recreate them in the content's new location.

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been included as part of the **2017 October 18th updates**.

You can now select multiple Artboards by shift-clicking the canvas and dragging the cursor over the artboards you would like to select.

Learn more at the official Adobe Support Doc on [Artboards](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/illustrator/using/using-multiple-artboards.html#Selectmultipleartboards).

Answer (score 2):

> In more recent versions of Illustrator, one can simply Shift-Click to
> select more than a single artboard and move them.

...and, just to make sure you don't Shift-Click them all one-by-one on the canvas, you can select *all* of them in two steps via **Artboards panel**:

1. Click the **first** Artboard
2. Shift-Click the **last** Artboard

*All* of them are now selected.

Answer (score 1):

I have another tip. Because I work on multi layers so I cannot group them into 1 square or something like that.

I draw an big artboard which contains all them, and move it into wherever I want. Of course this action will move everything and left all old artboard behind. And then I delete them (except the new artboard I create to move all my items).

Finally, I redraw each artboard according to their items. It still takes time, but I believe this way help you keep your flow in order, and keep all items in their own layers. And the most important thing is this way is faster than you have to move e-v-e-r-y artboard one by one.

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent version of Illustrator you can select multiple artboards by drawing a marquee around them. First hit shift+O to bring up your artboard tool. Then hold shift to draw the marquee around the artboards that you want to move. Also, if that doesn't work you can hold shift and click on them individually to select and then move them all at once. This is amazing!

Comment: this works. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to draw a rectangle to your desired artboard dimensions, then duplicate and move that rectangle using the method of your choice. Then, switch to the artboard tool and simply click on the rectangles. The tool will automatically create an artboard to the dimensions of the rectangle you are on.

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and play with it!

You can move your artboards one at time or many of them at once. All you have to do is select them, the content will move too.

Comment: What do you mean with "play with it"? Perhaps an image could be helpful?